# Cyrillic support on data retrieved from db and shown in browser

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am building a multilingual site, and the Menu items (Home, Photo.. etc) are read from the database, depending on what language the user sets. If he sets a language with Cyrillic letters, they don't show on the website (i just get quetion marks ). I have set the DB collation to utf8_bin, but it doesn't work on the site. 
I have tried 
    
,but it still doesn't work.

Comment: this is what i tried... it didnt show in the post <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: 1. What do you see if you do `View Source...`?  2. Try issuing this MySQL command from your php program immediately after you set up your connection, before you retrieve your Cyrillic language data. `SET character_set_results = utf8;`